# QR код в дополненной реальности для Android

Tags: android, opencv, qrcode

В целом задача тривиальная. Тестовая программа на Android

На стене весят qr коды, описывающие идентификатор датчиков (например температуры). На соотвествующий qr код наложить измеренное значение этим датчиком

Какие библиотеки порекомендуете для распознания кодов с камеры?
Подойдет ли OpenCV ?

Answer (score 2):

ZXing точно подойдет, распознавал им разные баркоды с картинок.

Опыт решения в [enSO здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134072/qr-code-scan-from-image-file):

```
public static String scanQRImage(Bitmap bMap) {
    String contents = null;

    int[] intArray = new int[bMap.getWidth()*bMap.getHeight()];
    //copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array
    bMap.getPixels(intArray, 0, bMap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight());

    LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), intArray);
    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

    Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
    try {
        Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
        contents = result.getText();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("QrTest", "Error decoding barcode", e);
    }
    return contents;
}
```

Напрямую с камеры ZXing умеет распознавать *из коробки* - без этих выкрутасов. Примеров в сети достаточно.

OpenCV помню тоже мучал, но почему то не подошел, за давностью уже не упомню почему.

Comment: Если в камере отобразится сразу несколько баркодов, Эта библиотека тоже их распознает? Или ей надо скармливать коды по одному?

Comment: Ну вот вы нам это и сообщите :) Мне это тоже крайне интересно

Comment: Вот еще на такую штуку наткнулся https://developers.google.com/vision/android/multi-tracker-tutorial